# accessing element (x,y) in cv::Mat with c++ api

Tags: c++, types, opencv, unsigned-integer

i'm aware of a lot of post about this argument and i've read a lot of them but i'm still confused. the problem are the types ( ohu, damn, this is c, i have to deal with with data types! ;-) ).

i'm using new supercool templated c++ api function `at`:

```
Mat mat32f(3, 3, CV_32F);
for(int i=0; i<3; i++) 
    for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
        mat32f.at<float>(i,j) = i;
cout << "Matrix of type: " << mat32f.type() << endl;
cout << mat32f << endl;
cout << mat32f.at<float>(1,2) << endl;
```

ok, here are float with 1 channel, no problem, the output is clear:

```
Matrix of type: 5
[0, 0, 0;
  1, 1, 1;
  2, 2, 2]
1
```

now just make some filter:

```
Mat mask;
inRange(mat32f, 1, 1, mask);
cout << "Mask of type: " << mask.type() << endl;
cout << mask << endl;
```

for here, alles klar, the output is just what i want:

```
Mask of type: 0
[0, 0, 0;
  255, 255, 255;
  0, 0, 0]
```

now i want to check if a certain point (mouse click? whatever) is inside the range.

```
int value2 = mask.at<char>(1,2);
cout << value2 << endl; 
unsigned int value3 = mask.at<unsigned int>(1,2);
cout << value3 << endl;
```

i remember from the first computer science class that a `char` is of the same size of an `unsigned int` (because of my mask type is 0 == `CV_8U`) so use a char. but `cout` grab it for a char and so show me some useless non-ascii symbol, so store it in an `int`.

here the ouput:

```
-1
256
```

what happened? a big mess. why -1?? or, again, why 256?? what happend?

Comment: char is not really the same size as an unsigned int.

Answer (score 3):

The comments from [OpenCV::Basic Structures](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/basic_structures.html) state this about Mat::at<>() methods:

```
// template methods for read-write or read-only element access.
// note that _Tp must match the actual matrix type -
// the functions do not do any on-fly type conversion
```

So what you are getting from a `Mat<float>` when you use `at<char>` or `at<unsigned int>` is likely undefined behavior (either from C++ or the Open library).

Your statement that "that a char is of the same size of an unsigned int" is also almost always not correct. I believe it is technically possible for `sizeof(char) == sizeof(unsigned int)` in C++ but I'm not aware of platforms/implementations where this is true. Even if it was true in your case it would be dangerous to use this assumption as it may not true on all systems your code may run on.

**More Detail**

According to the [OpenCV v2.4 Source](http://code.opencv.org/svn/opencv/branches/2.4/opencv/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp) the Mat::at() looks like (less debug code):

```
template<typename _Tp> inline const _Tp& Mat::at(int i0, int i1) const
{
    return ((const _Tp*)(data + step.p[0]*i0))[i1];
}
```

If you try to access the wrong type of data you are casting the raw array to the wrong type which only leads to no good.

As for why you would specify the data type into Mat::at(), can't you just do:

```
mat32f.at(i,j) = i;
```

and let the compiler automatically choose the correct template type?

Comment: Any idea what the point of `templated` at<T>() is, if one needs to know the matrix type anyway?

Comment: ok but so why also with unsigned int i don't get 255 but 256?

Comment: @nkint if no on the fly type conversion if being performed, I assume they just shoe horn some bits from a signed, floating point number into an unsigned integer. Basically, it is a dangerous consrtuction, and the reason I think the C++ API is anything but supercool :-)